# UIView in XIB using Autolayout is always 600x600

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, xib

I created a separate .xib because I wanted to design a `UIView` with `autolayout` outside of a viewController. I created the .xib, added the `UIView` and the constraints, using `wCompact hRegular`. Simple.

[image]

Then add it to my `viewController` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIView *header = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderSearch" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(header.frame));
[self.view addSubview:header];
```

But, when it is added, the frame size is 600x600 and I cannot figure out why.

What have I done wrong here that is forcing this strange size?

Comment: What frame size do you expect it to be?

Comment: Can you probably pin its height and width with a constraint? I assume the screenshot shows the correct frame size?

Comment: @gabbler - I was hoping for it to be 130 tall by the width of the superview, but not sure I can do that with a separate xib...

Comment: I think you can do this, use Freeform size for the topmost view and change its height to 130.

Comment: You'll have to manually add constraints for the header after you add it as a subview to be able to have 130 point height and same width as its superview. At the point of loading the nib its size is the size you see from the xib, but with constraint being set, its size will change to the constrained size.

Comment: Use this code in viewWillApear .. not viewDidLoad

Comment: @gabbler - Did that.

Comment: @gabbler - Any tips for doing that programmatically? I am pretty rusty doing it that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to uncheck 'Use size classes' in your xib

[image: uncheck size classes]

and the view frame size will be the one you set and not 600x600

Comment: But why the hell this issue exists? I was also going nuts!
If I have used Size classes then I should be able to set the View according to the Size Classes. Is there any reason of that?

Comment: And how the height of the View will be managed in case of different iPhones?

Comment: And if I want to use size classes?!

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to this.

```
header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:header];

NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:header attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:widthConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:header attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:130.0];
[self.view addConstraint:widthConstraint];
[self.view addConstraint:heightConstraint];
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is Xcode 8 disable "Use Trait Variations"

[image]

Comment: but then I lose the "View as" iPad possibilities; is this sure the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but in my case I didn't like to turn off trait variations or size classes. I also loading some views from XIBs but I use this handy helper category:

```
@implementation UIView (Initialization)

+ (instancetype)instantiateFromNib {
    return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self.class) owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
}

@end
```

I didn't want to introduce constraints written in a code so added a overriden `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method to my view controller like following:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self.firstView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.secondView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
}
```

In my case `firstView` and `secondView` are just an overlay to the whole view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is the best of correct ways:

```
- (void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
    [super willMoveToParentViewController:parent];

    self.view.frame = parent.view.frame;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    // adjust subviews here
}
```

View will get correct frame and adjustments will called only once on initialization.